# Google Chrome: How can I watch the state of the DOM while holding the mouse button

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, d3.js

in my DOM i have many SVG rectangles (each one in a separate ), that increase in size as long as the user clicks on (using the d3.js on-drag event). The size increases from 2px to 20px. It works, and all is fine - but:

I have a QUnit test that tests if the size is correct, and it currently runs red, telling me the size remained at 2px.

I tried to check the actual size in the DOM-Inspector, but as soon as I click onto the rectangle to fire the event, its group collapses in the DOM-Inspector and I cant look into. If I release the mouse, the group expands again, but its the original state again, which I dont want to inspect.

I want to look at the state of the DOM at the time when my mouse is clicked.
Is there any way to stop execution immediately?

I already tried using Event-Listener-Breakpoints and the element states :active/:focus etc, but without success.

Thanks in advance!
Kev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach one more `mousedown` event handler to your element. During this event handler you can proceed with your tests. Just make sure this handler is executed after the one that applies the changes to the element.

For QUnit you may use `var done = assert.async()` to get a function that you will call when your test is complete. At the end of the callback, just call `done`.

For example (using jQuery):

```
$('#element')
   .on('mousedown', function () { $(this).css({color:'red'}); })
   .on('mouseup', function () { $(this).css({color:'blue'}); })
   .on('mousedown', function () { 

          // this is the second callback I am talking about

          // make your tests...
          console.log($(this).css('color')) 

          // now it is done, call "done()"

   })
```

The color red will be logged.

Comment: Okay this worked, but I hoped for a solution without adding additional coding. But I came to the point that setting a breakpoint exactly on the sizechange also does the job. In a big app its just not that easy to find, and I hoped to find a solution just using the dev tools.

Comment: But this code you are adding only to your unit testing, not to your application. The way you can make without attaching another event handler is stubing/mocking your callbacks. This way you can check at the end of their execution that your element is at the expected state.

A breakpoint will not work for automated unit testings.